Efficiency of python iterables with sqlalchemy query's in_
I have a query with in_ filter. What I'm trying to figure out - is it more efficient to use tuples or sets as in_ arguments, or are they always converted to lists?
 1. ids = [1, 2, 3]
 2. ids = {1, 2, 3}
 3. ids = (1, 2, 3)

session.query(T).filter(T.id.in_(keys)).all()

All three types works correctly with in_, but...

What is the most efficient type for filter?
If I have different type, does it have any meaning to convert it to this efficient type?

I've looked through documentation but did not find an answer.

at the risk of being "that guy", if you are concerned about the performance of this when using something as "heavy" as an ORM, I would say you are looking at the wrong place to optimize

InElementImpl._literal_coercion checks that the input, if it's a literal, is an iterable and not a string, and then calls list on it.
Therefore passing a list is probably more efficient than passing another builtin iterable like a set or dict, and certainly more efficient than passing a custom iterable.
However to agree with python_user's comment, unless you're dealing with enormous lists the cost of conversion may be small relative to network wait times, result conversion etc.

+1. I tried to find this but failed, for some reason my debugger reached this code path, mind if I ask how you traced this? I did SomeModel.some_col.in_([]) and it was a no go (I got frame skips for some reason)

never reached this*

I did tbl.c.col.in_('ab') and the traceback showed me where to look:-)   To be honest I was trying to work out if any iterable would work, on the assumption that SQLA would just iterate without checking
